# Convert Std Object in xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

Hello i have this response from soaclient request:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AliquotaPolizzaCredito] => 7.21
            [AliquotaPolizzaPecuniaria] => 0
            [AliquotaPolizzaVita] => 14.82
            [AnzianitaPolizzaCredito] => 19

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AliquotaPolizzaCredito] => 7.464
            [AliquotaPolizzaPecuniaria] => 0
            [AliquotaPolizzaVita] => 15.533
            [AnzianitaPolizzaCredito] => 19
            [AnzianitaPolizzaPecuniaria] => 0
            [COMM_ATTIVAZIONE] => 0.0000
            [COMM_FIN_IN_TAN] => 0.0000
            [COMM_GESTIONE] => 0.0000
            [COMM_PROD_IN_TAN] => 0.0000
            [CodiceTabellaPlafond] => SIRIOFIN
```

Comment: I need to save it in xml file format....please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant nor the most flexible, but a solution would be to use get_object_vars.

Something like this:

```php
  // Suppousing that $response contains your array of stdClasses
  $domDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  foreach ($response as $key => $element) {
    $node = $domDoc->createElement('node_'.$key);
    foreach (get_object_vars($element) as $obj_var => $value) {
        $newElement = $domDoc->createElement($obj_var, $value);
        $node->appendChild($newElement);
    }
    $domDoc->appendChild($node);
  }
  $xmlFile = $domDoc->saveXML();
```

Than you can `file_put_contents` and save the content wherever you want.

The main problem here is to create a name for the root elements.